# Accessing props to mapped objects in render method

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of views managed in a home component that can be saved and loaded. The save and load functions work fine but I get the following error when calling it in the span's returned from the map function in the Footer.js render method

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

How can I access this function call in these elements?

Footer.js

```
export default class Footer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="footer hbox">
            <div className="views hbox">

                <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.getViewNames() }>Get Views</span>
                <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.saveView('test3')}>Save View</span>
                <span onClick={(e) => this.props.loadView('test3')}>Load View</span>

                    {this.props.getViewNames().map(function(viewName){
                      return (
                        <span onClick={(e)=>this.props.loadView(viewName)}>
                        {viewName}
                      </span>
                      );
                    })}

        </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: tl;dr: Use an arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for `getViewNames.map()`, and thus the lexical scope of `this` is not kept in your code -- which is interesting, considering you did use the correct approach everywhere else.

So just do:

```
this.props.getViewNames().map(viewName => {
    ...
});
```

Also see:

- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access props inside the map function is because `this` inside your function refers to the `context` of the map function, and not React Component. You will need to bind your map function to the React Component context by using `bind(this)` on the map function or `arrow functions`

**Using bind(this)**

```
export default class Footer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="footer hbox">
            <div className="views hbox">

                <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.getViewNames() }>Get Views</span>
                <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.saveView('test3')}>Save View</span>
                <span onClick={(e) => this.props.loadView('test3')}>Load View</span>

                    {this.props.getViewNames().map(function(viewName){
                      return (
                        <span onClick={(e)=>this.props.loadView(viewName)}>
                        {viewName}
                      </span>
                      );
                    }.bind(this))}

        </div>
    );
 }
}
```

**using arrow function**

```
export default class Footer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="footer hbox">
                <div className="views hbox">

                    <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.getViewNames() }>Get Views</span>
                    <span onClick={ (e) => this.props.saveView('test3')}>Save View</span>
                    <span onClick={(e) => this.props.loadView('test3')}>Load View</span>

                        {this.props.getViewNames().map((viewName) => {
                          return (
                            <span onClick={(e)=>this.props.loadView(viewName)}>
                            {viewName}
                          </span>
                          );
                        })}

            </div>
        );
     }
    }
```